# how to disable Push Notifications os popup on ios and avoid to launch app on main page

Tags: automation, appium, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I am doing automation using Appium and I came across 2 major problems.

1. How to dismiss SEND/PUSH Notifications popup on iOS which is system popup
2. If I install the application and uninstalled it and then again installed, It is launching the app with already user signed in. How can I avoid it to launch signed in instead of Showing on Sign in.

To cancel the PUSH Notification, I am using autoAcceptAlerts, which works but not always.

Comment: If I am understanding your question correct, after uninstalling and installing the application also you are logged in, is it?

Comment: yes, it is, But I think I can handle that now. 1 major problem currently is Notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though ideally uninstall and install shall not have leave the user logged in. But you can try this to logout the user after every relaunch, you can use `((AppiumDriver) driver).resetApp()` for resetting the application so that it launches back with the login page.

For dismissing the alerts `autoAcceptAlerts` should work. Another way to tweak it is to use `((IOSDriver)driver).SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();`. You can also try your hands on some methods mentioned [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5663).